# MATLAB Engine API for Python. Error: MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, python-packaging, matlab-engine

I'm working on my Master's Thesis. My director uses MATLAB, I use Python. So I need to run his MATLAB scripts on Python. There are many questions out there on this topic.

I tried to install Install MATLAB Engine API for Python (https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html). I came across the following problem:

`Error: MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version 2.7, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9, but your version of Python is 3.10`

Which alternatives do I have?

Another doubt I have: I checked my Python version by

`python3 --version`

and I get as an output: Python 3.9.7. I don't understand the Error then.

For the record, I'm using Ubuntu and Anaconda.

Comment: You can have as many pythons installed as you wish, make sure the command `python3` (or your matlab scripts) point to the one you actually want to use, or use the direct path to the `python.exe` you want rather than the shortcut `python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I get it working. Here's how:

HOW TO INSTALL MATLAB Engine API for Python.

**Short Answer:**

```
cd "matlabroot"\extern\engines\python

sudo \path_to_compatible_Python_version setup.py install
```

**Long Answer:**

1. You need Matlab correctly installed (I will skip this step)
2. Find the matlabroot (where is your Matlab installed). In Matlab's Command Window, type:

   ```
   matlabroot
   ```

   the ans is 'your matlabroot'. In my case, it is: '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2022a'
3. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   cd "matlabroot/extern/engines/python"
   ```

   Just remember to change 'matlabroot' with 'your matlabroot' (i.e. output in step 2)
4. Run `setup.py`. 2 ways:

   4.1 You can try: (it didn't work for me, but it is recommended in [Install MATLAB Engine API for Python](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

   4.2 If you get the error:

   ```
   error: could not create 'build': Permission denied
   ```

   try to run it with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo python3 setup.py install
   ```

   (I changed 'python' by 'python3')

Then you may get the version Error. It's something like:

```
EnvironmentError('MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version')

OSError: MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version [···], but your version of Python is [···].
```

You can check your Python with `python -V`

There is a chance you have more than one version of Python installed. You must make sure to use the direct path to the `python.exe` you want rather than the shortcut `python3`.

5. Let's do it. You can type into the terminal

   ```
   which python.
   ```

   This give use where python3 is located. (e.g. I get /home/user_name/anaconda3/bin/python3)

   Go to the directory `/home/user_name/anaconda3/bin` (we omited python3 because this refers to a Symlink, not a directory)

   There we should see (type `ls`) a symlink (word in Cyan) called `python3`

   we can [find the original file of a symbolic link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167631/finding-the-original-file-of-a-symbolic-link) by:

   ```
   readlink -f python3
   ```

   High are the chance, it is in the same directory (if not, go there). We need to search for a python version compatible with your matlab version. You can know that by the `OSError` or in [Versions of Python Compatible with MATLAB Products by Releas](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/python-compatibility.pdf)

   Type `ls` again in the same directory and search for a python compatible with your Matlab (green word). In my case, I found `python3.9` and it works with my Matlab version.

Now, you have a compatible version of Python located, repeat step 3. Run `setup.py` but this time change `python3` with the new python direction we just have found. In my case this look as follows:

```
sudo /home/user_name/anaconda3/bin/python3.9 setup.py install
```

All this worked for me. Good luck!

CU

Answer (score 0):

To install `matlab.engine` on Ubuntu/Debian for python 3.9 **and** configure it with a conda environment, use the following procedure:

0. Activate your conda environment on the commandline

   `$ conda activate <your_amazing_conda_env>`
1. Then, install matlab kernel

   `$ pip install matlab-kernel`
2. Change to the matlab installation directory

   `$ cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022a/extern/engines/python`
3. Install matlab.engine by directly pointing to location where your anaconda environment lives. For e.g.

   `$ sudo "/home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/bin/python" setup.py install`

Note that you need admin privileges in the last step.

---

If your installation is successful, you will get stack traces something like the following:

```
reading manifest file 'dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab
copying build/lib/matlab/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/engineerror.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/basefuture.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/futureresult.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/_arch.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/enginehelper.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/matlabfuture.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/enginesession.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/engineerror.py to engineerror.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/basefuture.py to basefuture.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/futureresult.py to futureresult.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/enginehelper.py to enginehelper.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/matlabfuture.py to matlabfuture.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/enginesession.py to enginesession.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py to fevalfuture.cpython-39.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py to matlabengine.cpython-39.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dist/matlabengineforpython.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
matlab.__pycache__.__init__.cpython-39: module references __file__
matlab.__pycache__.__init__.cpython-39: module references __path__
matlab.engine.__pycache__.__init__.cpython-39: module references __file__
creating 'dist/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg
removing '/home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg
Extracting matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg to /home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages
matlabengineforpython R2022a is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg
Processing dependencies for matlabengineforpython===R2022a
Finished processing dependencies for matlabengineforpython===R2022a
```

---

After that, you can test the working of the installation by importing matlab.engine in a python terminal.

```
In [1]: import matlab.engine

In [2]: matlab.engine.__spec__
Out[2]: ModuleSpec(name='matlab.engine', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fe58c4514f0>, origin='/home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg/matlab/engine/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg/matlab/engine'])

In [3]: matlab.engine.__name__
Out[3]: 'matlab.engine'

In [4]: matlab.engine.__path__
Out[4]: ['/home/mario/anaconda3/envs/chamois/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.9.egg/matlab/engine']
```